# Hyperlink to a function (to add new row under selected cell) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm following one of the tutorials I found here how to user HYPERLINK to call a function.
Can someone advise what needs to be done to get this work?

My hyper link: =HYPERLINK("#addLineClick()"," Add new line")

My Function:

```
Function addLineClick()

Set addLineClick = Selection

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
With ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow
.Insert

End With
```

One thing to note: When I run my function out of the VBA window it works like it should.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried the above method and it doesn't do anything when i Click the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a function from a `HYPERLINK()` formula on a worksheet, it will get triggered, but it suffers from the same restrictions that VBA functions are subject to when called from any other worksheet formula (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1).
That includes not being able to do things that alter the sheet, such as insert a row...

E.g. to illustrate: this formula
`=HYPERLINK("#tester()", "Test")`

Calls this VBA function:

```vb
Function tester()
    With Application.Caller                'the cell with the clicked-on link
        Debug.Print "clicked on", .Address 'works
        .EntireRow.Insert                  '## does nothing ##
    End With
    Set tester = Selection 'must return a valid range for the link destination
End Function
```

To get around this restriction you can instead use a regular hyperlink (via *Insert >> Link*) and an event procedure.

Eg:

In a regular module: the only job of this function is to return a valid range reference when the link is clicked

```vb
'This is a dummy link destination
Function tester()
    Set tester = Selection
End Function
```

In the worksheet module use the `FollowHyperlink` event to handle any clicks on links.  This event is not triggered by a click on a link created using `HYPERLINK()`, which is why you can't use that to create your links.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    'Figure out what action to take based on the link text
    Select Case Target.TextToDisplay
        Case "Add Row": Target.Range.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        'other actions handled here....
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note there's also a `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` event in `ThisWorkbook`, which could be used if you need to respond to links on a number of different worksheets in your workbook.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation, Tim. This is extremely helpful!