# Excel VBA - run macro (function) from hyperlink - not working each time

Tags: excel, vba, function, hyperlink, tooltip

my goal is to remove a button that displays an image I have inserted, starts a macro when clicked and displays a tooltip on mouseover.

After some searching I found the following solution: I create a shape, add an image to it and link it to a function and a tooltip using a hyperlink method.

The following answer from Tim Williams on your platform helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63059151

I also got the whole thing to work wonderfully. The code is a real game changer - many thanks for that.

But now to my problem:
There are certain cases in which, for whatever reason, the desired action is simply not executed correctly.

The following is an example:

The hyperlink is created with the following code:

```
Sub TOL_AddToSHP_Function_ToolTip(WSX As Worksheet, str_shpName As String, str_functionName As String, str_ToolTip As String)
    Dim shpX As Shape
    
    Set shpX = WSX.Shapes(str_shpName)
    shpX.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shpX, Address:="#" & str_functionName & "()", ScreenTip:=str_ToolTip
End Sub

Sub NAV_SetHyperlinktoButton()
    Call TOL_AddToSHP_Function_ToolTip(WS_NAV, "shp_NAV__Test", "§rHB_NAV__Test", "Test")
End Sub
```

The function and the following sub reads as follows:

```
Function §rHB_NAV__Test() As Range
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("shp_NAV__Test").TopLeftCell.Select
    Set §rHB_NAV__Test = Selection
        Call Test01
End Function

Sub Test01
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The following macro routines are considerably more complex in the original, which I cannot list in detail here.

In any case, "Sub Test01" is called as normal (tests confirm this), but the Application.ScreenUpdating line is simply ignored.

The same happens with the following sub:

```
Sub Test01
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Navigation").Cells(6, 2).ClearContents
End Sub
```

While the .clearContents method is simply ignored, a .Cells(6,2).value = vbnullstring, for example, works perfectly.

By the way, another user has already mentioned a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196909/23365989, unfortunately without an answer.

Perhaps one of you can think of a solution to the problem. In any case, I would be very happy about your help, as I believe that the "hyperlink button" itself has great potential.

Best regards,
MK91

Comment: Maybe look at a different approach using `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77144313/478884   This is more robust I think.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer. The problem is that "Workshee_FollowHyperlink" only works with "free" hyperlinks on the WS, but not with Links that are linked to a shape.

The problem has already been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858643

But even the solution shown there does not work with the combination of image + screentip that I needed.

The way I showed above seems to me (but maybe one of you knows a better one) to be the only one so far that combines exactly that. But for whatever reason it creates the problem I mentioned that not all actions are executed.

Comment: If you want some action to happen when the user clicks on a shape then have you considered linking the shapes to a macro which could do what you need?